# Copy/paste manager in system tray for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-recommendation, gnome-shell, clipboard-manager

Are there any copy/paste managers (for tracking copy history) which
integrate nicely in system tray on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[Clipboard Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/)". It's a

> Clipboard Manager extension for Gnome-Shell - Adds a clipboard indicator to the top panel, and caches clipboard history.

[image]

A rewrite of that extension with improved performance, new features, and bug fixes is also available [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4839/clipboard-history/).

Comment: this extension does not handle the Primary Selection buffer, so barely usable for me. (Glipper did.)